# htmlhelper dropdownlist selectlist to List<selectlist>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I create a select list and set it to viewbag then shot it as dropdownlist in view.. but it throws this exception:

> {"Cannot convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' to
>   'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'"}

here is my controller and html helper in view:

```
ViewBag.ProjeTipiList = valueSettingsService.GetRuzgarTurbunProjeTipiList().OrderBy(t => t.ProjeTipKod).ToSelectList(t => t.ProjeTipKod, t => t.Id.ToString(), "...Seçiniz...");

 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjeTipId, (SelectList)ViewBag.ProjeTipiList, "Select One")
```

how can I fix this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21464005/cannot-convert-type-system-collections-generic-liststring-to-system-web-mvc)

Comment: You have not shown the relevant controller code. If `ViewBag.ProjeTipiList` is `List<SelectListItem>`, then its `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjeTipId, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ProjeTipiList, ...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
ViewBag.ProjeTipiList = valueSettingsService.GetRuzgarTurbunProjeTipiList().OrderBy(t => t.ProjeTipKod).ToList();

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjeTipId, new SelectList(ViewBag.ProjeTipiList,"ProjeTipKod","Id", "...Seçiniz...") ,"Select One")
```

Comment: Yeah I made it with your way

Answer (score 1):

Because DropDownList does not accept a list of strings, It accepts `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>.`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjeTipId, ((List<string>)ViewBag.ProjeTipiList).Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m, Value = m }))
```